# Does the private keyword in a class level field declaration actually do anything?

Tags: java

I'm refactoring a bunch of classes, written by different people, which do not have consistent standards.  During the course of this, I came to ponder on whether there is any difference between these declarations:

```
public class foo(){

    int fooBar = 1;

    ......
```

and

```
public class foo(){

    private int fooBar = 1;

    ......
```

Please note that this is a question of semantics, I am fully aware of scoping, encapsulation etc.  The question is, does using the private scope annotation in a class field do anything?

Thanks for all thoughts..

(PS.  My current level of understanding says there is no difference)

Comment: It's not really semantics when the default scope allows for more access than a private scope.

Comment: There is no difference, in that both are syntax errors with those extra parentheses.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Absolutely there is a difference.  The [default access level for a class member in Java is package-private](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), not private.  This means that in the first version any class in the same package as `Foo` can access `fooBar`, while in the second version this is not the case.

Comment: Hmmm, feels embarrassed flush coming on.  I spent a good while Googling that and didn't find an answer.  Thanks.